# Sequelize.js models associations

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I am trying to build a tinder clone app, where i have two different type of users: a `player` and a `trainer` where they can match together. I have going through the docs trying to figure which are the right associations to implements between the `matches` table and `messages` tables, where a match record has a playerId and trainerId, the same goes to messages.

My question is:

how do i implement this, and when to apply belongsTo, hasMany, belongToMany association?

this is what i have done so far:

```
players.model.js

players.associate = function (models) {
  players.hasMany(models.messages);
  players.hasMany(models.matches);
};
```

```
trainers.model.js

teachers.associate = function (models) {
  trainers.hasMany(models.messages);
  trainers.hasMany(models.matches);
};
```

```
messages.model.js

messages.associate = function (models) {
  messages.belongsTo(models.players);
  messages.belongsTo(models.trainers);
  messages.belongsTo(models.matches);
};
```

```
matches.model.js

matches.associate = function (models) {
  matches.belongsTo(models.players);
  matches.belongsTo(models.trainers);
  matches.hasMany(models.messages);
};
```

Comment: So you wish to know how to register associations in Sequelize in a right way?

Comment: Yes, and how can two entities belongs to one record for example in the matches table?

Answer (score 0):

You can register all models and after that all their associations like this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var basename = path.basename(module.filename)
var db = {}
var models = path.join(__dirname, 'models')

fs.readdirSync(models)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js')
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(models, file))
    db[model.name] = model
  })

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})
```

Then you can export `db` object to use all models to query a data

For instance get all matches with a trainer and a player includes as objects:

```
const allMatches = db.matches.findAll({
  include: [db.trainers, db.players]
})
```